# Eclipse Code Completion (Java) / IntelliSense like in Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to configure Eclipse to behave more like VisualStudio?

The following thing is missing and I liked it very much in VS:

When the list of function names pop up and you begin typing you only get the functions that start with the fragment you typed. But in VS you get a list of functions that include the typed fragment.

For example:
type "Color" in Eclipse, you get nothing
type "Color" in VS you get: setBackgroundColor(), getBackGroundColor(), ... and so on

I think this is a very cool feature. So if you want to get all the functions that deal with color you just type it and get them.

Is this possible in eclipse?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need this for PHP? I don't know and don't like eclipse. Im using NetBeans for PHP and there is feature similar to IntelliSense.

Comment: Oh I am sorry not to mention that. I need it for Java.

Comment: You should try NetBeans anyway. It supports java.

Comment: In my opinion - after using Visual Studio 2003, 2005 and 2008 for years - Eclipse is totally mess and "disintegrated development environment". Net Beans is incomparably better. Not so good as VS, but good enough for me.

Comment: One more thing - writing "Color" to get methods containing that string works only in VS2010. In earlier versions you had to write first characters of method name. This is very innovative feature and i dont think if something like this will be available in freeware programming environments.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the choice to use NetBeans. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new Eclipse IDE (Juno) has got this feature:

Preferences -> Code Recommenders -> Subwords

Very cool and very very helpful!

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Code Recommenders doesn't exists in mine. How do I know if mine is juno ?

Comment: I don't know if something changed, but I also do not see the code recommenders preferences (anymore). You have to install the **Eclipse code recommenders** plugin from the eclipse marketplace.

Answer (score -1):

You will get a list of functions that START with the string you type AND are accessible from that scope ( are defined in the class or in it's superclasses).

Comment: You are wrong (-1). In Visual Studio 2010 you can write any part of name of method/property and IntelliSense shows you methods/properties containing that text, not only starting with it. I think this is best new feature of VS2010.

Comment: I'm talking about Eclipse. Did you read the question? Here's a little help: "Is there any way to configure **Eclipse** to behave more like VisualStudio?"

Comment: @MateiFlorescu: You answer is not an answer but just a fact. I know that I get a list of functions in Eclipse that start with the string...

My question was if it is possible to get functions (variables or whatever) that include the string I am typeing like in Visual Studio.